# Parse: [PFFacebookUtils reauthorizeUser:] callback never gets called

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse framework for social authentication. My app has a really simple method that requests post permission on Facebook.

My problem: **The block that I pass into reauthorizeUser: never gets called!**

```
+(void)acquirePublishPermissionsForUser:(DHUser *)user WithCompletion:(void (^) (BOOL succeeded, NSError *error))completion
{
    [PFFacebookUtils reauthorizeUser:user
              withPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                            audience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                               block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                   completion(succeeded, error);
                               }];
}
```

This method works fine. In this case, the Facebook app opens up and prompts for permission. Upon hitting OK, you're returned to my app. Both openURL & applicationDidBecomeActive get called.

This is in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // Handle Facebook authentication
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Handle Facebook Authentication
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

I've set a breakpoint to verify: my block never gets executed. It's really important, because I want to post to Facebook after I get permission. Otherwise it's kinda useless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a straight FB-API call ([[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions]).

It does weird stuff with my session and auth token data, but at least the callback gets executed. Definitely not a real solution but it'll do.